# How do I fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript

How do I fix this error?

> SimpleMap.js:35, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
>   undefined

```
    import React from "react";
    import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-     maps";

    export default function SimpleMap (props) {

    var markers = [{
        position:
        { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
        ,
        index: "1"
    }];
return (

    <section style={{height: "100%"}}>
        <GoogleMapLoader
            query={{ libraries: "geometry,drawing,places,visualization" }}
            containerElement={
      <div
        {...props.containerElementProps}
        style={{
          height: "100%",
        }}
      />

    }


            googleMapElement={
      <GoogleMap
        ref={(map) => console.log(map)}
        defaultZoom={3}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
        onClick={props.onMapClick}
      >
        {props.markers.map((marker) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              {...marker}
              onRightclick={() => props.onMarkerRightclick(index)} />
          );
        })}
      </GoogleMap>
    }
            ></GoogleMapLoader>
    </section>
);

}
```

Comment: `props.markers` is undefined on line 35.

Comment: Change line 6 from `var markers =` to `props.markers =` and see if that helps.

Comment: it gave this error.   SimpleMap.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property markers, object is not extensible .

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what the problem is. There are a lot of errors in your code, and
I can't see the whole picture from the snippets you posted. Really, you're going to have to learn how to debug JavaScript errors until you can track them all down. It's a lot of work, but I can't do it for you. 
To give you some direction, ideally your code should look more like this;

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps";

export default class SimpleMap extends Component {
  var { markers, containerElementProps, onMapClick, onMarkerRightClick } = this.props;
  markers = [{
    position: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    index: "1"
  }];
  var containerEl = <div {...containerElementProps} />;
  var mapEl = <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 }}
    onClick={onMapClick}
  >
    {markers.map((marker) => {
      return (<Marker {...marker} onRightclick={onMarkerRightClick} />);
    })}
  </GoogleMap>;
  return (
    <section>
      <GoogleMapLoader
        query={{ libraries: "geometry,drawing,places,visualization" }}
        containerElement={containerEl}
        googleMapElement={mapEL}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Then use that component like this;

```
import { SimpleMap } from './path/to/component';
...
// Inside your render function
<SimpleMap markers={yourMarkers} containerElementProps={this.props} onMapClick={yourOnMapClickFunction} onMarkerRightClick={yourOnMarkerRightClickFunction} />
```

But don't copy and paste that code, because it won't work. It's not tested and I wrote it without seeing the whole picture of your project. It's just a vague idea but it should give you something to go on.